# My First Time...

Tags: motion, criticism, animation

Hi everyone!

I just uploaded my first draft of a video a friend made.

I composed the music/othersounds.

I would love if you guys and girls could take a minute (it's actually shorter than that) and share what you think, any criticism (you could be mean if you like) comments or opinions.

thanks for your time!
didi

http://vimeo.com/17007887

Answer (score 1):

The splash sound at 00:10 doesn't sound right to me. The audience is probably viewing from an underwater POV throughout so it needs to be a splash that is heard from under the water. It will probably sound very different. I would prefer a little more sound to depict the life underwater, makes it more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

On the intro and outro - where reality is still the chalkboard and you are doing credits and titling - I would toss in your chalk write and erase sounds.

If this seems to generic, try reversing the chalk writing sounds to match your ambient sounds. To go deeper with that idea - If you have a reverb that can provide reverse reverb - try doing a 80 -100% wet reverse that is just the effect bounced and does not include the dry signal.

Turn up your bubbles in the mix when he dissipates - I could barely hear it on small speakers. To add to Hectors comment - to make the splash sound more underwater-y-ish, try a Lo-Pass filter with the cutoff somewhere around the mid-high range to get you started or to get a feel on how cutting highs can make something sound like its coming through a wall or from under-water perspective. Ad some bubbly extras to sell it.

Maybe some underwater swishes for the shark.

Fill it in with some interesting things and you've got a pretty neat artsy piece!

Finish it up!

-C3Sound

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the prompt feedback.

I'll re-post after re working things.

You guys rock. Peace.